# Añadir un auto_increment con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un formulario html que permite que un usuario introduzca el nombre_departamento y ese nombre se tiene que añadir como registro en una BBDD que tengo creada asociado a un código_departamento (primary key).

La cuestión es: ¿cómo consigo en el PHP, que es dónde hago la conexión con la BBDD de mysql, recojo el parámetro introducido en el formulario y lo agrego a la BBDD, que cada nombre_departamento se agregue junto a un código_departamento que sea auto incrementable? ¿Se puede hacer un auto incrementable en PHP?

Gracias.

Comment: Si la columna está declarada como auto_incremente en la BD no tienes que preocuparte de generar nada, pues el SGBD creará el valor de forma automática cada vez que se inserte un nuevo registro.

Comment: Sí, si se lo añado a la BD luego al insertarlo en PHP supongo que se incrementaría automáticamente, ¿pero se podría hacer sin tocar la BD, solo a través de PHP?

Comment: Claro. Una vez definida la columna como auto_increment la misma se aumentará cada vez que una inserción ocurra (o intente ocurrir), sea desde PHP, desde Java, desde C ... desde el patio de tu casa o desde la luna. Quien maneja los datos es la BD, y PHP es sólo una herramienta, como cualquier otra, a través de la cual podrás acceder/manipular/modificar esos datos. Otra cosa, los auto_increment crecen también en inserciones fallidas, debes tenerlo en cuenta si es sumamente importante para ti no tener saltos en ellos.

Comment: Piensa que los gestores de bases de datos son en sí mismos herramientas potentes y que no conviene en ningún caso intentar re-inventar la rueda del otro lado (como esto que intentas, de manejar un auto_increment desde PHP). Esto es no sólo despreciar a la base de datos, sino que, imagina que se escriben 50 aplicaciones en diferentes lenguajes/plataformas para acceder a ESA base de datos, y defines el manejo de auto_increment del lado del lenguaje. ¿Ves la locura que sería eso, 50 manejos de auto_increment cuando la BD lo hace por sí misma, y además lo hace mejor? Y eso vale para más cosas...